# How can I create a dynamic URL in php?

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I am new in PHP and MySQL.

Here's what I've tried so far and I can't understand how to make URL with PHP.

What I want to do is to create a dynamic web page about a particular book. I already created and have some data in my MySQL database to play with.

I've got a function to clear the special characters in the book titles.

```
function seo($s) {
$tr = array('ş','Ş','ı','İ','ğ','Ğ','ü','Ü','ö','Ö','Ç','ç');
$eng = array('s','s','i','i','g','g','u','u','o','o','c','c');
$s = str_replace($tr,$eng,$s);
$s = strtolower($s);
$s = preg_replace('/&.+?;/', '', $s);
$s = preg_replace('/[^%a-z0-9 _-]/', '', $s);
$s = preg_replace('/\s+/', '-', $s);
$s = preg_replace('|-+|', '-', $s);
$s = trim($s, '-');

return $s;
}
```

Example

```
echo seo($booktitle);
```

.htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/(.*)-(.*)$ /book.php?id=$1 [L,NC]
```

Link type

```
echo "<a href='http://sitename.com/".$bookid."-".seo($booktitle)."'>".$booktitle."</a>";
```

Output I want

```
http://sitename.com/id-book-title
```

The thing is, I don't understand how I can pass the $bookid from the url to the php itself dynamically. I think I need to retrieve book_id from my database and assign it to $bookid variable, is that correct? But how can I connect it to the URL?

For instance, when I type the url http://sitename.com/5-the-trial I need to get the page for the book that has the id of 5.

What's missing here? Can you guide me to the right direction to create dynamic urls? I am both in need of guidance (learn this, search that, etc) and a specific answer to my question, if that's possible.

Comment: You can use a php framework like Laravel or Symfony, they will do that job for you

Comment: @Ragnar You don't think a whole framework for a simple URL rewrite is just a little excessive? (though, granted Syfony is pretty modular)

Comment: @Ragnar, thank you for your comment. But my PHP knowledge is limited at this moment, so I want to learn PHP for a few months, then I will be more comfortable with PHP frameworks in the future, I think.

Comment: Depending on the size of the project, I'd recommend a framework as well. Url rewriting is pretty simple in Laravel. First you'd create a route like "/book/{id}", point it to your controller...something like BookController@show. Write the relevant server side code to pull the book info from the db based on the id you're passing in, and then render the view with the data you just got. There's a bit of a learning curve at first, but if you're doing anything in PHP a framework is really the way to go.

Comment: That's right @CD001, for a single page website using a framework is excessive. It was just an idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not quite clear what your asking. If you want to create a page that lists the urls of your books, then you are not far off with your echo statement. You just need to populate $bookid and $booktitle from the database. .htaccess is not involved.

```
echo "<a href='http://sitename.com/".$bookid."-".seo($booktitle)."'>".$booktitle."</a>";
```

But if you want to unpack the URL of the link the user clicked, then you need to look at the query string passed to the page. .htaccess breaks up the URL for you and passes the $1 parameter into your script. To read the url in PHP try the following

```
parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'],$query);
if (array_key_exists('id',$query)) {
   $books = explode("-",$query['id']);
}
```

This will create an array with the book id in the first element ($books[0]), and the first word of the title in the second etc. (If you wanted to use this approach and have the whole title in the second you might want to use a different character to delimit the id from the title to the character you use to replace spaces.

Comment: This helped me a lot, thank you. Actually I want to create the sitename.com/id-booktitle page where all information is being showed about a particular book.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your rewrite rule to this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^([^-]+)-(.+)$ /book.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```