# How to create clean url fetching data from mysql in php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, mysqli

I want to know how to create url **directly** dynamically fetching data from mysql in php?

Let assume I have a database table named "Products":

```
1) id
2) seller_id
3) Product Code
4) Product Image
5) Product Description
```

- Let assume there are 5000 products added in it or more.
- Let assume my domain name is: www.xyz.com

Now what I want is to create urls from product table's seller ids like www.xyz.com/sellerid1

If new seller id added then I will get url dynamically automatically and on that page get all related products related to seller_id from table "Products"

I want url like

```
www.xyz.com/sellerid1
www.xyz.com/sellerid2
www.xyz.com/sellerid3
```

My File Name is where I want to fecth data from "Products" table: seller.php

I dont want url like:

```
www.xyz.com/seller.php?id=sellerid1
www.xyz.com/seller.php?id=sellerid2
www.xyz.com/seller.php?id=sellerid3
```

I want if someone hit the url directly on addressbar like:     www.xyz.com/sellerid1 then all the products related to sellerid will show. It can achieve this by     www.xyz.com/seller.php?id=sellerid1 but no user will remember that type of url. I want www.xyz.com/sellerid1

Sorry, two questions in one but I have no idea how to achive this dynamically.

Any idea or suggestions would be welcome.

Comment: Can you use .htaccess?
Check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388959/url-rewriting-with-php

Comment: @ Van Tho , Thanks for the reply. Yes, I can use . htaccess but wiil it remove .php from all urls? Actually This is my first project so I never use .htaccess. And how to create url from database and show all related products this is the first task I have to finish.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I create a dynamic URL in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27570522/how-can-i-create-a-dynamic-url-in-php)

Comment: @Thomas Jeriko, exactly like the question you have suggested I am also confused - The thing is, I don't understand how I can pass the $sellerid from the url to the php itself dynamically.  Like www.xyz.com/sellerid1

Comment: @Sarah Why don't you use a framework like laravel or codeignitor?

Comment: @ Jestin Sebastian,  I am new and I have given semi developed project with no framework.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have sellers table?
if yes, so you can fetch sellers from table and make link dynamically.

query:

```
SELECT id, name FROM tbl_sellers WHERE enabled=1 LIMIT 10;
```

html (index.php):

```
$result = []; // execute $query

// loop on result
foreach($result as $item)
    echo "<a href=\"www.xyz.com/seller.php?id=sellerid{$id}\">{$name}</a>";
```

seller.php:

```
// Getting request id from url parameters and cast to integer
    $sellerId = (int)str_replace('sellerid', '', isset($_REQUEST['id']) ? $_REQUEST['id'] : '');

    if(!$sellerId || $sellerId < 1){
        exit('Seller not found.');
    }


    $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_products WHERE seller_id='{$sellerId}'";
    $result = []; // execute $query

    // fetch query
    exit(var_dump($result));
```

Comment: @ Ata amini, Thanks for the valuable reply. This concept I know and have mentioned in my question above, I don't want to create urls like www.xyz.com/seller.php?id=sellerid1. I want if someone hit the url like: www.xyz.com/sellerid1 then all the products related to sellerid will show. The thing is, I don't understand how I can pass the $sellerid from the url to the php itself dynamically.

Comment: use this line: `$sellerId = (int)str_replace('sellerid', '', isset($_REQUEST['id']) ? $_REQUEST['id'] : '');`

Comment: Getting parameters from url can done with: $_GET, $_REQUEST and $_POST if your request method is post.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use MVC framework like Laravel,Codeigniter, or other framework use MVC.
MVC Framework , can do, exactly you want, like

```
www.xyz.com/sellerid1
```

or 
you can do like this but the link not form like

```
www.xyz.com/sellerid1
```

but like

```
www.xyz.com/sellerid/1
```

index.php :

```
<?php
//get request url
$request_uri = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
// print_r($request_uri);
if($request_uri[2]=='sellerid'){
    include 'test.php';
}
?>
```

test.php :

```
<?php  
    echo $request_uri[2].'/'.$request_uri[3];
?>
```

.htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

And how to create link is like :

```
<?php  
    $url="http://www.example.com/";
    $theproduct=array(...);//Fill with your sellerid
    foreach ($theproduct as $key) {
        ?>
            <a href="<?=$url.'sellerid/'.$key['seller_id']?>"></a>
        <?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: @ Thomas Jeriko, Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately I am not using it. No framework. Without framework is this not possible?

Comment: ah , i see. yes you can do that without framework , see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27570522/how-can-i-create-a-dynamic-url-in-php

Comment: im tested on localhost

Comment: @ Thomas Jeriko, Thanks Thomas for a great help. I want to know what if sellerid is: best-book-seller-in-newyork then the url will be www.xyz.com/best-book-seller-in-newyork

Comment: @Sarah u can do ,like $request_uri =explode('/',str_replace('-', ' ', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));

Comment: its work, if the title of the book use '-' for the space

Comment: @ Thomas Jeriko Thanks. I am trying it at the moment and hope it will work for me. Many Thanks Thomas.

Answer (score 0):

Using core php here. add the below lines in your .htaccess file. Assuming your default file is index.php here.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-f
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^seller/([^/]+)$ seller.php?sellerid=$1
```

Now when you will try to open the URL http://www.yoururl.com/seller/{your_dynamic_seller_id_comes_here}. suppose you are opening the URL http://www.yoururl.com/seller/1 then you will get the dynamic seller id from the below code (seller.php).

```
<?php
$sellerid = $_GET['sellerid'];
//get the result from database query 

$dbquery = "SELECT * FROM Products WHERE seller_id='$sellerid' ";
//execute the above query and use the result and do your stuff.

?>
```

Hope this helps you.